# NullPointerException for some reason

Tags: java, swing

I am writing this program using the javax.swing library. The "purpose" of the program is that when you push button one the text of the label says button1 if you push button 2 the text of the label says button 2

```
right.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            label.setText("right")          }
    });
```

for some reason this creates a null pointer exception.
I really don't get this.
Can you guys help me?

Kind regards

Comment: It gets an NPE because the `label` hasn't been set. You need to make sure it is set before you use it.

Comment: the label was set but the right was not set :( I am very sorry :)

Comment: You mean the `"right"` string or did you make that bit up?

Comment: This is where a debugger is very helpful in debugging your code.